# How to change settings position?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I'm pretty sure someone already asked this question but I can't find information about it. How to change position of this settings:
[image]
I've tried to look in preferences but I just don't know what's the name of this thing. By default this settings is at top of viewport, but mine is at bottom.

Comment: right click > Flip to Bottom (or Flip to Top)?

Comment: @moonboots yeah, worked with "View", "Select", ... part. For another part needed to right click on mode - Header > flip to top again. Thank you!